# c++11 multithreading memory error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the following code:

```
somefunc(string s, semaphore* sem) { 
     //some functionality
     sem->signal();
}

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    semaphore sem(0);
    vector<string> arr;
    for (string& s : arr) {
        ++num; 
        thread(somefunc, s, &sem).detach();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        sem.wait();
}
```

I am getting `SIGSEGV` errors inside `std::string` allocation on the line where `thread()` is. Is there something wrong with this code? `semaphore` is a custom class that uses a mutex and a conditional variable.

Comment: What kind of memory errors?

Comment: sorry, I just added the detail

Comment: "`std::string` allocation memory errors" - What kind of errors? `std::bad_alloc`? `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: I don't see any synchronization between the main thread terminating and the spawned threads terminating. That is, the main thread has some chance to terminate before the detached threads terminate and clean up their resource. One of the perils of using detached threads.

Comment: `arr` is empty, so the code doesn't create any threads. There can't be an error at the indicated line, since it is never executed. Further, "a custom class that uses a mutex and a conditional variable" gives no hint of what that class does or how it's implemented. Post real code.

Comment: It might be just a simplification in your example, but you could replace the detach/semaphore with a simpler join.  boost.thread has thread_group to make things even simpler. Apart from that, I don't see any obvious flaws in the presented code that could cause a crash, so it is probably in the not-presented code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your real code, but my guess is that when the string reference `s` is being copied inside `thread` it is no longer valid because the main thread has already exited the scope containing `arr`.

Running your code under valgrind or a similar memory checker should help diagnose the problem.